# different output of same value in different situations - array

Tags: php, arrays, fractions

I can't understand why these arrays give me different outputs:

**• this value 1/4 came from a table (db)**

```
id | value
...
2  | 1/4
3  | 1/7

echo $matrix[0][2]; //show 1/4
```

**• but if i do = 1/4**

```
echo $matrix[0][2] = 1/4 // show 0.25
```

this occurs in all fractions values. For example 1/7 in first example show 1/7, but in second show 0.142857142

So, my question is why ? I want always decimal value, but the first code as i said, is not working with decimals.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value from the database is a **string** and the value you set yourself is a **float**.

If you are using MySQL you can use [mysql_fetch_field](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php) to know a field type, wich can be usefull when you're working with *MyISAM* (MySQL always return strings).

You have the easy/ugly solution:

```
$var = '1/4';
echo (float)eval('return '.$var.';');
```

An other solution:

```
$var = '1/4';
$tmp = explode('/', $var, 2);
$tmp = $tmp[0]/$tmp[1];
echo $tmp;
```

But I think the best solution is to save the result in your database (0.25 for example) and to cast the results into float when you're getting them.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you are retrieving string values from the database.  In the second example, you are evaluation a mathematical expression.

Your best bet would be to do something like:

```
$t = explode("/", $matrix[0][2]);
echo ($t[0] / $t[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cos' in the first example value have a string type and in the second you're calculating math function and the answer have a floating point type.

If u'll use this construction "echo $a = '1/4';" the output will be the same.